# function for special characters

Tags: php, function

Is there a function like htmlentities or htmlspecialchars that will convert special characters (`&quot;`) or what have you, while preserving `<br>`, `<span>` .etc on user entered data after post?

Comment: Before printing the post use html_entity_decode(string) to change it to HTML again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get the required thing:

```
<?php

      $str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

       //Encoding
       $encoded = htmlentities($str);

      //Decoding note that here the quotes aren't converted
     echo htmlspecialchars_decode($encoded, ENT_NOQUOTES);
 ?>
```

If you want to save the entries in DB as they are use addslashes for storing as it is

Answer (score 0):

I hope you search for `htmlspecialchars_decode()`.

An example is below.

```
<?php
$str = "<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>\n";

echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);

// note that here the quotes aren't converted
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES);
?>
```

[Php.net link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).